# Excel formula to return all matching strings within a cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have one column that looks like this:

```
    screws
    nails and screws
    nails
    screws, nails
```

I'm trying to create a new column containing only given keywords, so the output would look like this:

```
    screws
    nails screws
    nails
    screws nails
```

I've been using =IF(SEARCH("nails",A1,1),"nails",IF(SEARCH("screws",A1,1),"screws","")) but of course if the first statement is true it doesn't bother searching for the next.

Comment: Are you only trying to get rid of Commas and ANDs?

Comment: Afraid not - the text here is just a simple example. There's a lot of other unpredictable text; I'm just trying to pick out the keywords. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What Excel are you using.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: @readtheiron I have updated my answer. Is this what you are after?

Comment: The ISNUMBER example works great on my data! The first one kept erroring out, and I couldn't figure out why, but the second works very nicely.

Comment: If you can get your hands on Office 365 Excel this formula: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"screws","nails"},A1)),{"screws","nails"},""))` as an array will work.  If you have more words you just add them to the array parts, or you can refer to a range of cells with the words instead.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a shot. The actual data has a lot of keywords, and I was wondering if an array might make sense to handle it. Still getting the hang of arrays, and need practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following **IF/SEARCH** formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("nails",A1,1)>0,"nails ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("screws",A1,1)>0,"screws ",""),"")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the **ISNUMBER/SEARCH**:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("screws", A1)),"screws ","")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("nails", A1)),"nails ","")
```

[image]